# Can I use any kind of method within a get and set accessor of a public property of a public class

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a class BaseTableC inheriting from an interface I_BaseTableC ,both having a set of public properties.

Can I access the "altered"(altered by MethodAlterValue) value provided by get/set accessors by reference of BaseTableC.Property1 or BaseTableC.I_BaseTableC I_refernce as I_reference.Property1?

As of now, I don't get an error, but the Property1 never shows the altered value as provided by the get/set accessor.

```
public class BaseTableC : IBaseTableC
{
    public string Property1
    {
        get { return MethodOriginalValue(_Property1); }
        set
        {
            if (! String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                _Property1 = MethodAlterValue(value.TrimEnd());
            else
                _Property1 = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: during execution, _Property1 does show the altered value, but BaseTableC.Property1 doesnt not.

Comment: Why are you altering the value both going into the the field and coming out? Wouldn't it suffice to alter it only going in?

Is it perhaps causing problems that by the time the value has made a round trip, it has gone through MethodAlterValue twice?

Comment: Edited the code, they are different methods, one alters and one changes it back.(Encrypt/Decrypt).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong (because maybe I'm misunderstanding the question): the setter of the property encrypts the value; the getter decrypts it. That means whenever you call BaseTableC.Property1, you're calling "MethodOriginalValue". If you want to get the altered value, either create another property called something like `Property1Altered`, or change the getter to return _Property1 and create another property to return `MethodOriginalValue(_Property1)`

Comment: Your question does not make sense to me Property1 is the accessor -- it never has a value.  When you read or write to it in code the compiler will generate the function calls you have above.  What exactly do you mean by Property1 does not have a value?

Comment: @JoshPart, yes, you are right. so its not possible to access both encrypted as well decrypted value through same property as per context of the code..? I actually wanted to avoid creating separate properties in the first place..

Comment: @Hogan, ok, lemme put it this way, can I access both original and altered value through the same property? Or do I have to write separate properties for that purpose?

Comment: @ShwetaSaxena - you have to write separate properties or not use properties.  Not clear on your requirements.

Comment: Please refer to @JoshPart's comment for explanation

Comment: @ShwetaSaxena If you want to return more than one value on the same property, you need to return something else than a string (a dictionary, a list, a tuple, a struct, an object of another class...). Other way is to create not a property but a method with a parameter to define what value you want to get.

Comment: @ShwetaSaxena you're welcome; just keep in mind that, if you change the property type, is both in and out.